# Is there an algorithm for converting a CFG in Greibach Normal Form into a CFG in strong GNF?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars, normal-forms

A CFG is in strong GNF when all rewrite rules are in the following form:

$A \rightarrow aA_1...A_n$

where $n \leq 2$.

Comment: What are your thoughts? Have you tried coming up with such an algorithm? Have you tried searching the net for such an algorithm?

Comment: I had already constructed the algorithm for converting a CNF CFG into a GNF CFG. From there I thought it'd be easier to convert a GNF CFG into a SGNF CFG but I have yet to find a way. I had looked around but it appears **strong** GNF is not a widely used term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such an algorithm is described in [Koch and Blum, Greibach Normal Form Transformation, Revisited](http://theory.cs.uni-bonn.de/ftp/reports/cs-reports/1996/85151-CS.pdf).